# php RegEx working on my local server - not working on remote host running php4

Tags: php, regex

I am pretty sure I know what the issue is, but I cannot resolve it for the life of me and I just don't know what to do at this point.

All I am trying to do is qualify the input of a first and last name field. This code IS working on my local server running php5:

```
    <?php 
$regex = "John's Jerod";
 if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\'\,\.\s]+$/", $regex)) {
          echo "ERROR!";
      } else {
   echo "NO ERROR!";
   }
?>
```

As expected, this returns NO ERROR!, but when I run this on my live server, I only get ERROR with the same data.

I've determined it's the comma throwing it off! And I am pretty sure, because the php version I am running does an auto escape like \' in the name John\'s, so I ran striptags on all output and still the same error.

DOes anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can resolve this?

I've got about 8 hours in the "bug" as of now. Been through 40+ variations of the RegEex with no luck.

I check and triple checked all of my form field names, vars etc to ensure everything matcheds and all else is OK.

SOS

Comment: Are the servers' OS's and PHP versions the same or similar? It could be line endings if you are doing this from Windows to Linux/Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex doesn't need all those backslashes. It should be this:

```
"/^[A-Za-z',\.\s]+$/"
```

Also, you refer to using striptags(). You should be using stripslashes() if your server has magic quotes enabled.

[Edited regex]

Comment: Nope. That does not work either. And it was my error. I am using stripslashes() like: $first_name = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']));

Comment: David Powers, I think you posted the exact expression I did? Did you mean something else?

Comment: @David Powers, You posted the exact same expression the OP did >.>

Comment: How weird. The regex that I entered did not have backslashes in front of the single quote or the comma, but it looks as though it has been added in by the system.

Comment: @OldWest, I think your problem is caused by passing the value to mysql_real_escape_string(), which is escaping the apostrophe ready to insert the value into the database. Try preg_match() before passing it to mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: Many apologies. I must have pasted the original regex back in by mistake. Have edited it now.

Comment: @David Powers, nope. That changes nothing. Same error. This one is frustrating. Bummer : (

Comment: @David Powers. Wait. You might have been right and my error again.. Will let you know in a second. Running some tests.

Comment: @David Powers, Thanks much for your advice. After a while, all of this code starts to look the same! So this was all solved by: 1) using preg_match() prior to mysql_real_escape_string(). 2) Updating the RegEx to the suggested less slashes. 3) Sample code: $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['fname']));

Comment: Not sure why your answer is showing a -1 ?? I checked it though now showing green check. I am new to stackoverflow, so excuse my newbieness : )

Comment: @OldWest Don't worry. I'm new here too. I think someone gave me -1 because of my mistake in pasting your original regular expression, rather than the amended one. Silly mistake, but one that was easy to correct as soon as it was pointed out to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking specifically for `1`. Per the documentation, it returns `FALSE` (strict check) on error, `0` (strict check) for no matches, or `1` if there is a match (since it stops at one).

Also, per my own preference, I use the ~ symbol for my regex's. And like David Powers said (only he didn't correct it at all), you don't need most of those backslashes (only for the period and the space).

```
<?php 
$regex = "John's Jerod";
 if (preg_match("~^[A-Za-z',\.\s]+$~", $regex) !== 1) {
          echo "ERROR!";
      } else {
   echo "NO ERROR!";
   }
?>
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:** Also, you say you're using `strip_tags`? That strips any HTML tags in a string -- not slashes. You need `strip_slashes` to strip slashes, *not* `strip_tags` ;)